# For Logic --n in Call by Value in C

Tags: c, pass-by-value

I'm new to programming and currently learning C from The C Programming Language by Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie. I have a difficult at section 1.8. Why when I'm trying to change

```
for (i = 1; n > 0; --n)
```

into

```
for (i = 1; n > 0; ++n)
```

the output is,

```
0       1       1
1       2       3
2       2       3
3       2       3
4       2       3
5       2       3
6       2       3
7       2       3
8       2       3
9       2       3
```

Why this is happen?

Here is the full code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int power(int m, int n);

main(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d %7d %7d\n", i, power(2,i), power(3,i));
    return 0;
}

int power(int base, int n){
    int p;
    for ( p = 1; n > 0; --n)
        p = p * base;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to make that change is the question. It does not make logical sense given the way that `n` is used in that code, so of course it doesn't work.

Comment: You loop while `n` is larger than `0`, and each iteration *increase* `n` so it will (theoretically) *never* be equal to or smaller than `0`. What is the purpose of that change? What did you think it would accomplish?

Comment: first, `i` is unused so `for (; n > 0; --n)` should work. second, `for (i = 1; n > 0; ++n)` is infinity loop where `n > 0`.

Comment: Your excerpt doesn't match the complete example. Clean up your question, that may show you your error.

Comment: This might be a good point where you start using a debugger. Step through your function and watch the variables.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax of for loop is

```
for (initialization expr; test expr; update expr)
```

which means, the first expression will be executed once, 
the test expression is checked every time for ture or false every time the loop starts, and update expression is evaluated unconditionally on every time loop start.

in this case, n-- is evaluated before checking n > 0,  which means the loop will stop when n becomes 0. but if you change it to n++, n will keep on increasing every time of the loop, until the integer is overflowed.

you can change the loop to the following to get output:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the power methods' for-loop you decrement n until in some iteration of the loop n is zero (no longer n > 0). If you now change the loop to increment n every iteration, n will continue growing until you get an integer overflow ([Wikipedia: Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)) and n becomes negative at which point your program will terminate.